# Wordpress - How can I auto login a user after they have been approved by admin?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cookies

I am building a site that requires all new users to register before they can view the site. Once the user is registered, the admin must approve the newly registered user. However, I would like for the newly approved user to automatically be logged in, instead of having to login.

Is there a way to do this with Wordpress, either with or without a plugin? I am using the New User Approve plugin.

Perhaps, if upon registration a cookie is set on the new users machine that is cross-checked to authenticate the new user?

Comment: You can extand the auth cookie duration to a year (for example), as long as the user doesn't manually clear his cache or manually disconect himself the user will remain logged in.

Comment: see the following https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114439/preventing-session-timeout

Comment: @amarinediary thank you for your suggestion, but the auth cookie is only set once a user has logged in, and I would like to avoid the login process all together.